# Facebook login issue 2015

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies

Recently i made a simple software using c# http request but now it seems there is a problem logging in facebook getting and sending request

here is few lines of code that used work

```
         string email = "email";string pw = "pw";string PostData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", email, pw);




         CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
          HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com"); 
          request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
          request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
          //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
          HttpWebResponse response =  (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          cookies = response.Cookies;




        string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php? login_attempt=1";
          string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}",  "anything@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
          HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
          getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
          getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
          getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
          getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
          getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
          getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
          getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
          getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";




          byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
          getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;   
          Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
          newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
          newStream.Close();




          HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
          {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = sourceCode;   

          }
```

First ,saving cookies after sending request then using it to login on facebook.(so that it won't mention "Please enable cookies...")

and Now it doesn't work

Anyone know the issue or should i switch to httpclient (though i haven't used httpclient much)

thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook does not want you to login using such tools/bots, and is actively taking measures against it. If you want to interact with Facebook, use their API.

Comment: i am just looking to create a simple software to schedule my post to my facebook profile

Comment: That is likely against Facebook policy. Regardless, the approach you explained here could even get you banned from FB.